# How to display Leaderboard Sets in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, game-center-leaderboard

I was trying to get this to work all last night but it wouldnt. Can anyone help?

I use the following code to display a leaderboard:
  `gameCenterViewController.leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardId`

This works fine for normal leaderboards, but fails to load any leaderboard sets, when I use the leaderboardSetId.  Can you link directly to leaderboard sets and if so how do you do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please do refer below code and cross verify your configuration.

Hope this would help you.

```
import GameKit
class YourViewController: UIViewController, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {

var gcEnabled = Bool() // Stores if the user has Game Center enabled
var gcDefaultLeaderBoard = String() // Stores the default leaderboardID

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 self.authenticateLocalPlayer()

}

func authenticateLocalPlayer()
{
    let localPlayer: GKLocalPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(ViewController, error) -> Void in
        if((ViewController) != nil) {

            // 1 Show login if player is not logged in

            self.presentViewController(ViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else if (localPlayer.authenticated) {

            // 2 Player is already euthenticated & logged in, load game center

            self.gcEnabled = true

            // Get the default leaderboard ID
            localPlayer.loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler({ (leaderboardIdentifer: String?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                } else {
                    self.gcDefaultLeaderBoard = leaderboardIdentifer!
                }
            })


        } else {
            // 3 Game center is not enabled on the users device
            self.gcEnabled = false
            print("Local player could not be authenticated, disabling game center")
            print(error)
        }

    }
}


    @IBAction func clickToLeaderBoard(sender: UIButton) {

        let gcVC: GKGameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
        gcVC.gameCenterDelegate = self
        gcVC.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards
        gcVC.leaderboardIdentifier = "YourLeaderboardId"
        self.presentViewController(gcVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

func saveScoreOnGameCenter()
{
    let leaderboardID = "YourLeaderboardId"
    let sScore = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: leaderboardID)
    sScore.value = Int64(10)

    GKScore.reportScores([sScore], withCompletionHandler: { (error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            print("Score submitted")

        }
    })
}

func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gcViewController: GKGameCenterViewController)
{
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

**Update**

Also please do check your leaderboard configuration from back end.

Some good posts are here.

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-game-kit-framework/

https://developer.apple.com/game-center/

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html

Comment: Ive got the normal leaderboards showing its just the leaderboard sets that dont show.  I tried replacing the leaderboardIds with the leaderboard set IDs in my code but that didnt work.  I think this solution assumes that is all you need to do?

Comment: Yes, this is minimum needs to do, can you try integrating my code i have given here and check.

Answer (score -2):

Having ensured that you have authenticated the local player and your leaderboards set in iTunes Connect, you will need to [report your scores to GameCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Achievements/Achievements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH7-SW19) ensuring you use 64bit Int.
Now you can add this to display the leaderboard for the local player:

```
func showGKGameCenterViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
    if gameCenterIsDisabled {
      print("Local player is not authenticated")
    }
    let gameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gameCenterViewController.delegate = self
    gameCenterViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.default

    viewController.presentViewController(gameCenterViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```